# Forgot to make new database for civi... how uninstall?

Tags: installation, install

I installed CIVI but forgot to create a new database just for civi... how do I undo or uninstall and start over?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `civicrm.settings.php` and run the installer again.  Here's where to find it:

- Backdrop: `<webroot>`
- Drupal: `<webroot>/sites/default`
- Joomla: `<webroot>/components/com_civicrm`
- WordPress: `<webroot>/wp_content/plugins/civicrm`

Note that this will NOT remove the old tables from your existing database.  To do that, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589278/sql-deleting-tables-with-prefix).